# Is this a mathematically sound way of working with infinity? (Calculus 2 Assignment)

Tags: calculus

$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{n},
\qquad N\in \ \mathbb{N}$

$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n},
\qquad N\in \ \mathbb{N}$

...

$S_N \ge \frac{1}{2} (log_2(N) + 2).$

Let's take the limit of the right side of the inequality as $N$ grows to infinity:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2} * (log_2(n) + 2)} = \infty$

So $S_{\infty}$ or $S$ is greater than some infinity, so:

$S = +\infty$

(My goal is to show $S = +\infty$ here.)

Comment: What is $S$? What does "$S$ is greater than some infinity" mean?

Comment: There is a theorem that covers this; it's like the squeeze theorem except that it deals with infinite limits instead of finite ones.

Comment: @anomaly apologies, clarifications are in my edit. As for "
  is greater than some infinity" - this is what I'm asking about. If I understand correctly, there are different infinities? So if S is greater than some infinity its equal to infinity? idk, how can I say this better?

Comment: "Different infinities" is a thing in set theory, not in analysis. You goal is simply to prove that that $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = \intfty$ which means: $\forall M \exists N$ such that $\forall n \ge N$, $S_n \ge M$.

Comment: If your goal is to prove that $S = \infty$, there are plenty of proofs online for showing the harmonic series diverges to $\infty$.